# How does one include TR1?

Tags: c++, include, c++11, portability, tr1

Different compilers seem to have different ideas about TR1. G++ only seems to accept includes of the type:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
#include <tr1/memory>
...
```

While Microsofts compiler only accept:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
...
```

As for as I understand TR1, the Microsoft way is the correct one.

Is there a way to get G++ to accept the second version? 
How does one in general handle TR1 in a portable way?

Comment: TR1 is not actually part of the C++ Standard, so the "correct" way of including these non-standard header files must be moot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install boost on your machine.
Add the following directory to your search path.

<Boost Install Directory>/boost/tr1/tr1

see here [boost tr1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_tr1/usage.html) for details

Now when you include <memory> you get the tr1 version of memory that has std::tr1::shared_ptr and then it includes the platform specific version of <memory> to get all the normal goodies.

Comment: +1. Since TR1 appears to be "lets import these boost classes into the standard"

Comment: I do `#include "boost/tr1/unordered_map.hpp"` and it uses the tr1 implementation if it is available.

Answer (score 14):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <unordered_map>
    #include <memory>
#else
    #include <tr1/unordered_map>
    #include <trl/memory>
#endif
```

Comment: You should probably base the conditional compilation on the compiler, not the platform (`_WIN64` is real): `#if defined( _MSC_VER ) && ( _MSC_VER > 1300 )`, for example.

Comment: On last include, tr1 is misspelled as trL ;)

Comment: If you are doing std::tr1::unordered_map , do you still need to include both <tr1/unordered_map> and <tr1/memory> or can you include only <tr1/unordered_map>? Trying to reduce the amount of libraries included.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the best way would be to simply use [boost](http://boost.org) libraries for now, as in many cases they have alternatives with a similar interface to TR1 features, and are just in a different (but consistent) header path and namespace. This has the advantage of working on compilers that haven't even *begun* implementing C++0x. And there are plenty of useful boost libraries that aren't in TR1 at all :)

Alternately, on G++, you could try passing --std=gnu++0x on the command line. This works for <unordered_set> and <unordered_map>, at least. Then to make it available in std::tr1:

```
namespace std { namespace tr1 { using namespace std; } }
```

This is evil, naturally. I highly recommend the boost approach instead :)

Comment: Using -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x doesn't work as it will only make std::unordered_set<> available, but not std::tr1::unordered_set<>.

Comment: @Grumbel, updated with an evil hack that will make it available in std::tr1

Answer (score 3):

A tad hacky perhaps, but you could simply add the compiler tr1 directory to your include path.

Answer (score 2):

If under Windows, add the 'tr1' directory to the system path.  Then `#include <memory>` should work.

Comment: do compilers on windows use the system path as well as the include path when resolving includes?

Answer (score 2):

I asked myself the same question. Unfortunately, the technical report doesn't say how the headers should be included. It only defines that the extensions should be in the ::std::tr1 namespace.