# How to get headers for unordered_set in gcc v4.1.2?

Tags: c++, gcc, header-files, tr1, unordered-set

I'd like to use unordered_set without installing Boost. I tried to add `--std=gnu++0x` but it is not a recognized option.  Does v4.1.2 include unordered_set?  If so, how do I get the header file for it?

This is a Centos 4 machine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1228402/1172428 might gives some hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unordered_set` is in the purview of the standard C++ library, not `gcc`, the compiler (although most programs built using `gcc` are linked against `libstdc++`).

The way you generally include it is `#include <tr1/unordered_set>`. Then, to use it, you must either do a `using std::tr1::unordered_set;` or qualify the name each time.

The C++ standard version you choose to use doesn't have much effect because that's the *language* standard, and the availability of standard library constructs is semi-independent.

Comment: I tried the normal include which is not located by compiler. Does this work for you on v4.1.2?

Comment: `unordered_set` is in the purview of `libstdc++`, **not** `glibc`. And the `libstdc++` itself is actually *a part of* GCC. So, uhm, it actually has a lot to do with the compiler and nothing to do with `glibc`.

Comment: @Fanael I really should have said "the standard library". I'll change that. And you can actually build C++ programs linked against alternate libraries, believe it or not.

Comment: @Borealid: I don't believe. But seriously, what's the likelihood of the OP using alternate library and not knowing if and where it has `unordered_set`?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, gcc-4.2 did not have unordered containers at least not in namespace std.  I know -std=c++0x was not in place till around gcc-4.3.

Have you tried this:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_set>
...
  std::tr1::unordered_set<int> usint;
...
```

Notice the tr1/ in the header.

Having said that, gcc-4.1 is pretty old.  Any chance you could try say gcc-4.5 or 4.6 and use the std container?